# MsGesture, swipe in different directions in metro style app

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have this code working fine for finger swipe gesture i.e. if I swipe my finger it fires the event and calls nextMonth() function. Now is there any way that I can check if I swiped in up direction and down direction so that I can call two different methods on the two different gestures.

```
            var myGesture = new MSGesture();
            var v = this.element.querySelector(".bartouch");
            myGesture.target = v;
            v.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd", handleListner,false);
            v.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", handleListner, false);

        function handleListner(evt) {
            if (evt.type == "MSPointerDown")   
                {
                myGesture.addPointer(evt.pointerId);
                return;
            }
        that.nextMonth();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Use `MSGesture`, and handle the [`MSGestureStart`, `MSGestureChange`, and `MSGestureEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh968035.aspx) events to calculate the translation of the users finger (or fingers), and see if they're in the right direction. The event object returned by `MSGestureChange` includes `translateX` & `translateY` properties that tell you how far the user has moved their finger. There is a detailed sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-Instantiable-deda69ca/sourcecode?fileId=57998&pathId=770530612).
2. Use `Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer` and use the [gesture settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturesettings.aspx) on the gesture object to set the gesture to be specifically X translate, or Y translate. The [Ball Eight sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-26918bb3/sourcecode?fileId=43578&pathId=1052877166) shows how to do this. It primarily involves creating the GestureRecognizer class, and feeding it events by handling `MSPointer[Down|Move|Up|Cancel]` DOM events on the DIV you want to look at the interactions on, and passing them to your (shared) recognizer instance through it's `process[Down|Move|Up]Event` handler.

Personally, I would recommend using 2, rather than 1 -- while it is more difficult to setup, you will end up with the user having a consistent gesture experience for swipes, flicks etc. rather than you having to hand tweak your gestures as you would if you chose method 1.

Comment: Your Ball Eight example link doesn't work. Any chance of an updated link or a link to another example that demonstrates the behavior you outline in 2?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used [HammerJS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) in one of my games to handle gestures in various directions.

This is all the code I needed to handle all four directions:

```
var hammerOptions = { swipeVelocityX: 0.1, swipeVelocityY: 0.1 };
Hammer(contentContainer, hammerOptions).on("swipeleft", function(event) { moveBlocksLeft(); });
Hammer(contentContainer, hammerOptions).on("swiperight", function(event) { moveBlocksRight(); });
Hammer(contentContainer, hammerOptions).on("swipeup", function(event) { moveBlocksUp(); });
Hammer(contentContainer, hammerOptions).on("swipedown", function(event) { moveBlocksDown(); });
```

Where `contentContainer` is a div containing the content, and each direction has a function to handle the gesture further.